# Проверка правильности ввода числа с консоли

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит некоторую последовательность цифр с консоли, если он ввел все верно без пробелов и букв - выходим из цикла. Иначе - выводим надпись о неправильности ввода и просим повторить попытку. Ниже код, но вот только он даже на корректный ввод просит повторить попытку. Что не так?

```
bool test = true;
while (test)
{
    int i = 0;
    n[i] = getchar();
    while (n[i] != '\n')
    {
        i++;
        n[i] = getchar();
        if (n[i] >= '0' && n[i] <= '9')test = false;
        else
        {
            test = true;
            cout << "Введены некорректные данные, повторите попытку: " << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cin.flush() cin.ignore(100000); как-то так после неудачной попытки.

Comment: @pavel, можно чуть подробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: Грубо говоря,  если ввели не число то вы сразу же, не дочитывая строки выдаете сообщение, потом вы эту же строку читаете. И да, перевод строки вы не там проверяете. А лучше читайте сразу всю строку а не по 1 символу через cin.geltline например, а потом и проверяйте её уже.

Comment: @pavel, то есть лучше сделать так: cin.getline(n)? Не понял, можете привести конкретную реализацию?

Comment: @pavel, while (test)
 {
  getline(cin, N);
  for (int i = 0; N.size(); i++)
  {
   if (N[i] >= '0' && N[i] <= '9')test = false;
   else
   {
    test = true;
    cout << "плохой ввод";
    break;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: @pavel, не работает

Comment: А N это что? Если char*  так size как-бы бесполезно брать у него

Comment: Посмотрите нормальное плюсовое решение в *Update* моего ответа...

Comment: Кинул пару примеров, как такие задачи можно программировать

Answer (score 0):

Символ конца строки `'\n'` не проходит проверку `if (n[i] >= '0' && n[i] <= '9')`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы последним вводите символ `'\n'`, который **не** проходит ваш тест...

Сделайте тогда уж так:

```
char n[1000];
for(bool ok = false;!ok;puts("Retry"))
{
    ok = true;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    fgets(n,1000,stdin);
    if (n[strlen(n)-1] == '\n') n[strlen(n)-1] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; n[i]; ++i)
        if (!isdigit(n[i]))
        {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
}
```

Тем более что в вашем коде при неправильном вводе остатки неверного ввода остаются в буфере и портят вам жизнь...

**Update**  Вот совсем простой код на **C++**:

```
string s = "a";
for(;s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != string::npos;)
{
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    getline(cin,s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> test = false;
> ```

Это должно быть перед вторым циклом.

> ```
> n[i] != '\n'
> ```

А это - внутри, до if'а.

> ```
> n[i] != '\n'
> ```

Тут ещё надо делать

```
n[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать проверку так. Работает на все, включая пробелы точки и тире, и буквы

```
    bool test = true;

    while (test)
    {
        cout << "Введите число, факториал которого вам нужно найти. Число доолжно быть от 10 дo 100: ";
        getline(cin, N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N.size(); i++)
        {
            if (N[i] >= '0' && N[i] <= '9')test = false;
            else
            {
                test = true;
                cout << "Некорректный ввод, вы дурак!" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (N.size() != 2)
        {
            test = true;
            cout << "Введенное число должно быть из диапозона [10; 100]" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: По-моему, вы где-то зашорили семи себя на этом тесте... `int d = 0; for(;;) { scanf("%d"<&d); scanf("%*[^\n]s%*c"); if (d >= 10 && d <= 100) break; printf("Еще раз: "); }` Кстати, если уж так приспичило проверять каждый символ - используйте `isdigit`...

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понимаю, Вы хотите вводить длинные десятичные числа без знака. Я думаю, что иногда полезней просто показать, чем долго и нудно исправлять.

Вот пример вроде бы под Ваши требования из вопроса:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int skipnl (int n, int *err) {
  *err = 1;
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');

  return n;
}

int
get_digits (char *input, int lim, int *err)
{
  int c, n = 0;

  *err = 0;
  if (lim < 1) {
    printf("call error: lim = %d\n", lim);
    return skipnl(0, err);
  }

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') {
      if (!n)
    continue;
      return n;
    }

    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      if (n < lim)
    input[n++] = c;
      else {
    printf("too long, max: %d\n", lim - 1);
    return skipnl(n, err);
      }
    } else {
      printf("incorrect input: '%c'\n", c);
      return skipnl(n, err);
    }
  }

  return n;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char s[1000];
  int n, err;

  while (!feof(stdin)) {
    fputs("Enter: ", stdout); fflush(stdout);
    err = 0;
    n = get_digits(s, 999, &err);
    s[n] = 0;
    if (n && !err) 
      puts(s);
  }


  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что переменная в которую getchar()-ом читаем символ имеет тип **int**, а не char (!) (читайте `man getchar`).

=======

Возможно, для конечной цели вычислений с неопределенно длинными целыми более привлекателен подход, когда мы сразу получаем число в динамической памяти (выделенной malloc). Для этого идеально подходит функция GNU [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) (если у Вас ее еще нет, то либо поставьте GCC, либо сами напишите ее (хотя бы в качестве упражнения в программировании)). Вызывая эту функцию мы вместе со строкой сразу получаем и ее длину.

Введенная строка проверяется и сразу преобразуется в "перевернутую" (т.е. младшие цифры числа в начале строки) последовательность десятичных цифр (по цифре на байт) в виде чисел, уже хорошо подходящих для дальнейших вычислений.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int check_cvt_chr (char *p)
{
  if (*p < '0' || *p > '9') {
    printf("invalid input: '%c'\n", *p);
    return 0;
  }

  *p -= '0';
  return 1;
}

int
check_convert (char *s, ssize_t l)
{
  size_t i = 0, j = l - 1; 

  for (; i < j; i++, j--) 
    if (check_cvt_chr(s + i) && check_cvt_chr(s + j)) {
      char t = s[i];
      s[i] = s[j];
      s[j] = t;
    } else
      return 0;

  return i == j ? check_cvt_chr(s + i) : 1;
}

static void
print (char *s, ssize_t l)
{
  while (l)
    putchar(s[--l] + '0');
  puts("");
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  size_t sz;
  ssize_t len;
  char *str = 0;

  while (fputs("Enter: ", stdout), fflush(stdout),
     (len = getline(&str, &sz, stdin)) > 0) {
    str[--len] = 0; // erase  '\n' at the end
    if (check_convert(str, len))
      print(str, len);

    free(str);
    str = 0;
  }


  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Естественно, в вычислительной задаче после (или вместо) `print()` введенные данные надо где-то сохранить (копировать байты как раз необязательно, а вот указатель `str` для дальнейшего ввода надо обнулить) и вызывать `free()` только для ввода с ошибками.

Оба примера компилируется в Linux gcc и g++.